# YUI Autocomplete renders under other page elements in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, yui, z-index

I'm working now on a page that has a column of boxes styled with sexy shadows and corners and whatnot using the example [here](http://www.schillmania.com/content/projects/even-more-rounded-corners/).  I have to admit, I don't fully understand how that CSS works, but it *looks* great.

Inside the topmost box is a text-type input used for searching.  That search box is wired up to a [YUI autocomplete](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/autocomplete/) widget.

Everything works fine in Firefox3 on Mac, FF2 on Windows, Safari on Mac.  In IE7 on WinXP, the autocomplete suggestions render underneath the round-cornered boxes, making all but the first one unreadable (although you can still see enough peeking out between boxes that I'm comfortable IE7 really is getting more than one suggestion).

Where could I start looking to correct the problem?

Here's what success looks like in FF2 on WinXP:

[image]

And here's what failure looks like in IE7:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The working solution I finally implemented was based on reading [this explanation](http://aplus.rs/lab/z-pos/) over and over again.

In the underlying HTML, all of the blue rounded corner elements are DIVs, and they're all siblings (all children of the same DIV).

The z-index of the autocomplete div itself (which is the great-great-grandchild of the rounded corner container div) can be arbitrarily high, and it won't fix this issue, because IE was essentially rendering the entire contents of the search box *below* the entire contents of the "Vital Stats" box, because both had default z-index, and Vital Stats was *later* in the HTML.

The trick was to give each of these sibling DIVs (the blue rounded corner containers) descending z-indexes, and mark all of them position:relative.  So the blue div that contains the search box is z-index:60, the "Vital Stats" box is z-index:50, "Tags" is z-index:40, and so on.

So, more generally, find the common ancestor of both the element that is getting overlapped and the element that is overlapping.  On the immediate children of the common ancestor, apply z-indexes in the order you want content to show up.

Comment: Of the dozen answers I've looked at to Internet Explorer's infuriating z-index bug, this one makes rational sense and (unlike the others) it immediately worked for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Jeremy,

Sorry for this being so late, but hopefully the answer will be of use to you in a future project.

The problem here is that IE creates a new stacking order anytime there is an element with position:relative, meaning that z-index itself is not the only controlling factor.  You can read more about this here:

http://therealcrisp.xs4all.nl/meuk/IE-zindexbug.html

To solve the problem, if I'm understanding your problem correctly, apply position:relative to the container that wraps your whole autocomplete implementation (and then position:absolute to your results container).  That should create an independent stacking order in IE for those elements that allows them to float over the other position:relative stacks that appear later in the page.

Regards,
Eric

Answer (score 1):

I'm not *totally* understanding the setup that's leading to the problem, but you might want to explore the useIFrame property of the YUI Autocomplete object -- it layers an iframe object beneath the autocomplete field, which allows the field to then float above the objects that are obscuring it in IE's buggy layout.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.AutoComplete.html#property_useIFrame

But the docs say that this matters in 5.5 < IE < 7, so this might not be the issue you're experiencing.  So again, without totally understanding the setup you're working with, you might also want to try to experiment with various [z-index](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index) values for the autocomplete field and the surrounding block-level elements.

Comment: Thanks, the iframe trick actually has solved some problems in IE6 for me, but doesn't appear to influence this issue.

Comment: Sorry about that -- did you give the z-index property a go?  Based on the screenshot you posted after my answer, it looks like that's likely to be the case.  I think that there's a developer toolbar for IE that will let you see the z-index of various elements...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the z-index of the auto-complete div is a larger number than the divs that constitute the rounded corner box. Microsoft puts the z-index of the top elements to 20000 or 100000 I believe. Might be wise to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem to this, I fixed it by basically just changing z-index for the different divs. Just setting higher number for each div in the order it should display.